# Prepend a fixed set of numbers to a sequence

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have the following variables:

```
Code = "XYZ123"
First = 13
Last = 27
```

I need to fill in the rows between `First` and `Last` in `N` column with

```
<fifth character in the code (i.e. '2')> & 
<fourth character in the code (i.e. '1')> & 
<sixth character in the code (i.e. '3')> & 
<sequence starting from '1' with a length of 'Last - First + 1'>
```

So, my desired output for each cell in "N" column should be

```
N13: 2131
N14: 2132
N15: 2133
.
.
.
N27: 21315
```

P.S. It would be great if the VBA solution is not based on a for loop.

Comment: You can do it both by formula and vba.

Comment: Without a loop? I can only come up with Range("N13").Formula2 = "=""213""&sequence(15)" in VBA (Excel 365) but that feels a bit like cheating. It's easy to generate a sequence of numbers in VBA e.g. Range().Dataseries but I can't work out how to add a string without a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still maybe a bit of a cheat, but you could try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim code As String, tmp As String
    Dim i As Long, First As Long, Last As Long, Rows As Long

    code = "XYZ123"
    First = 13
    Last = 27
    Rows = Last - First + 1
    
    tmp = Mid(code, 5, 1) & Mid(code, 4, 1) & Mid(code, 6, 1)
    
    Range("N" & First).Resize(Rows, 1).Value = Evaluate(tmp & "&" & "sequence(" & Rows & ")")
      
End Sub
```

to avoid the loop. Apologies for recycling some code from @Harun24hr's answer, it does the job very nicely so no point in re-inventing the wheel. I don't believe there is any way of doing it without a loop natively in VBA.

*Worksheet Equivalent:*

```
=LET(First,13,
Last,27,
Rows,Last-First+1,
Code,"XYZ123",
Tmp,MID(Code,5,1)&MID(Code,4,1)&MID(Code,6,1),
Tmp&SEQUENCE(Rows)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below sub-

```
Sub FilSequence()
Dim code As String, tmp As String
Dim i As Long, First As Long, Last As Long

    code = "XYZ123"
    First = 13
    Last = 27
    
    tmp = Mid(code, 5, 1) & Mid(code, 4, 1) & Mid(code, 6, 1)
    
    For i = First To Last
        Cells(i, "N") = tmp & i - (First - 1)
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I am sorry for editing my question a minute ago. I would be grateful if you could find any needed edits in your answer based on my question updates.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it possible to have a way to do it without using for loop?

Comment: Try edited answer. You have to use loop. You may use Do while, While Wend instead of for loop.